# Why dotnet --list-sdks does not show installed SDKs on Windows 10?

Tags: .net-5

I have **Microsoft .NET SDK 5.0.102 (x64)** installed on my **Windows 10**, but when I do `dotnet --list-sdks` nothing shows up? I could see the SDK installed from Windows Apps & features. Thank you.

**Edit:**

Doing `dotnet --info` shows the following

```
$ dotnet --info

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.2
  Commit:  cb5f173b96

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.11 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.1 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: What does `dotnet --info` show you? The issue can be related to architecture, see here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3242

Comment: @mxmissile thank you for the tip, I just updated my question with the result from doing `dotnet --info`, please see above.

Answer (score 21):

Removing `c:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe` from global System Variables Path helps for me.

Comment: This worked for me, there were two installations of dotnet on my harddrive and both visual studio and cmd were finding the wrong one.

Answer (score 17):

There are multiple .NET installations on your system and they are getting mixed up.

You have one installation that's x86 (`C:\Program Files (x86)`) - and has no SDK - and another that's x64 - and has the 5.0.102 SDK.

When you run `dotnet`, you seem to be running the x86 version.

The SDK you have installed is the x64 version.

You should try and figure out which architecture you need and uninstall the other one.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I ended up re-installing VS2019 to get around this issue.

Comment: Worked for me - both .\program files (x86)\dotnet and .\program files\dotnet were in my path. removing the x86 version from the path worked! now visual studio 2019 will load my project

Answer (score 8):

CHECK YOUR ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES!

I just ran into this issue and discovered that some how my `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\` environment variable was above my `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` which meant that whenever I ran the `dotnet` command it was using the x86 version.

Answer (score 1):

See [Windows or Visual Studio can't find the latest installed .NET SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67049414/windows-or-visual-studio-cant-find-the-latest-installed-net-sdk)

If the first SDK installed on the machine is a different bit size, you won't see the latest SDK

Answer (score 0):

You can use sdk check command.
E.g.

```
dotnet sdk check
```

Output will be similar to below image, but will depend upon what sdk you have installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I renamed that file c:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe, then it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

It might be because in your production environment you installed the runtimes and not the SDKs. We do that on our production boxes. The dotnet --list-sdks will not work.

Try dotnet --list-runtimes