# Why .net core 3.1 projects can be created without installing the 3.1 SDK?

Tags: .net-core, .net-5, .net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.0

run the command "**dotnet --list-sdk**" in cmd window, the following msg shows,

```
5.0.404 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.101 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

which means .net core 3.1 sdk not installed.

but indeed I can create and make .net core 3.1 projects using VS2019, even using VSCode.
Why .net core 3.1 apps can be created without 3.1 SDK?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692530/why-dotnet-list-sdks-does-not-show-installed-sdks-on-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @Hans Passant

I figure it out  after reading your link and searching more results.
.NET 5 SDK is forwards compatibility with .NET Core 3.1 SDK, but .NET runtime not. 
I can create and build .NET Core 2.1 console app in VS2019 successfully because .NET 5 SDK intalled in my computer, 
but it fails when running the app because .NET Core 2.1 runtime not installed.