# Windows Terminal Not showing all .net SDKs

Tags: .net, windows, windows-terminal

I have a set of projects which build okay within Visual Studio 2022.

When using a build script from Windows Terminal 1.16.... it fails to recognise the SDKs and only shows 6.0 (see below).

```
dotnet --list-sdks                                                                                                                      
6.0.307 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\sdk]
```

How to I get Windows Terminal to see the installed versions of .net?

[image]

Comment: Could be this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65692530/why-dotnet-list-sdks-does-not-show-installed-sdks-on-windows-10

Comment: Yes I have Program Files and Program Files (x86) .net versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to put the path for the 64 bit dotnet directory in the path higher up the 32 bit version, and then I see all the .net versions.