# Console application solutions can't be build and run in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6.0. When I create a console app, in my solution explorer, I only get an icon for a solution. But there are no project and class items, no properties and references.

[image]

I made many console applications some years ago, but I think it was an older version of .NET, but I am not sure. The structure then was like this:

[image]

Another problem is that I can't build and execute the console app, with or without debugging. Options are locked.

[image]

I recently made a few MAUI and Blazor apps for learning and practicing and I didn't have any problems with these types of apps.

This is the output of `dotnet --info`:

[image]

Comment: Your solution file has no projects. Did it used to? How did you made the sln and project files? How did you open the Project.cs file in VS?

Comment: @gunr2171 I just created the solution the usual way. File > New Project > I choose Console App, then I set my project name and location. I tried the "place solution and project in the same directory" option checked and unchecked, not working either way...
Then I choose the Framework version., and the button "Create". Just like any project, be it MAUI, Blazor, Console, WPF...

Comment: What happens if you close Visual Studio, then double click the sln file from File Explorer?

Comment: @gunr2171 I can choose via which app I want to open, and when I choose Visual Studio 2022, it opens the solution in Visual Studio, but Solution Explorer is the same as in the question above (only the name of the solution in the solution tree).

Comment: As for the cs file, my Program.cs file is opened in the editor section of the Visual Studio since I created the solution. But the same Program.cs is not in the solution explorer, under solution. @gunr2171

Comment: @gunr2171 I can also access the Program.cs via Folder View

Comment: I'm not sure why your solution would have no projects, but you can re-add it by right clicking the solution in the solution explorer and add an existing project (use the csproj file). Don't use Folder View when you're trying to compile/debug code.

Comment: @gunr2171 I've got "The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found." And then the path to my csproj file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256247/discussion-between-gunr2171-and-losmincl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [a lot of back and forth](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/256247), the problem was that

1. Your dotnet CLI install was the x86 version, and
2. The x86 version of the CLI had no SDKs installed.

This was also evident by running `where dotnet` in CMD. In my case where I'm using the x64 version, "C:\Program Files\dotnet" comes before "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet". You had it backwards, even though your OS is x64. My guess is that your dotnet install is really old and that's what it was *way* back in the day.

There's two ways to fix this:

1. Install the .NET SDK for x86, and keep using x86.
2. (which we ended up doing) Changing the CLI to be x64. This was done by changing the system-level PATH variable to have "Program Files" above "Program Files (x86)", as suggested [in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65692530/1043380).